# Taking square of summed numbers

Tags: python

This code adds all natural numbers up to 10, then takes the square of that sum in Python. Where did I go wrong?

```
def square_of_sum():
    sum = 0
    for x in xrange(11):
        if x <= 10:
            x + sum = sum
            x += 1
        else: 
            print sum*sum
            break
```

Comment: What output did you get, and what output did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I see you like [**Project Euler**](http://projecteuler.com) :)

### Solution

I think this is what you meant by your code:

```
def square_of_sum():
  sum_ = 0
  for x in xrange(1, 11):
    sum_ += x
  return sum_ ** 2
```

To rewrite this more idiomatically, use generator comprehensions and built-ins:

```
def square_of_sum():
  return sum(range(11)) ** 2
```

If your performance conscious, you can eliminate the loop by noticing that your finding the sum of an arithmetic series:

```
def square_of_sum(x):
   print (x * (x + 1) / 2) ** 2
```

### Fixes

As to why your code isn't working, it's b'coz of many reasons.

First of all, I think you're confused about how the `for` loop in Python works. Basically, it just loops over an array. You didn't have to check and break when x became greater than 10, nor increment it. Read up on the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) on how to use the `for` loop. To see an example of when to use it, see the [wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Secondly, variable assignments are done with the variable on the left and the expression to be evaluated on the right. So `x + sum = sum` should really have been `sum = sum + x` or `sum += x` for brevity.

Thirdly, `sum` is a built-in function. You probably didn't want to nor shouldn't over-shadow it, so rename your `sum` variable to something else.

And last, `sum*sum` is equivalent to just raising it to the power of 2 and you can do that using the `**` operator as so: `sum ** 2`.

Hope this helped you understand.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the errors in your code:

```
def square_of_sum():
    s = 0
    for x in xrange(11):
        s += x
    print s**2
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
def square_of_sum(n):
    print sum(range(n + 1)) ** 2
```

or, to eliminate the loop:

```
def square_of_sum(n):
    print (n * (n + 1) / 2) ** 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems. First of all, `sum` is a builtin function, so you probably don't want to name anything that, so use a variable called something like `total` instead.

Second, variables assignment is done with the variable on the left and the expression on the right, so `x + total = total` should be `total = x + total`, or `total += x` for brevity.

Third, since the case when `x == 11` is basically just a return case, it should be outside the loop.

And, finally, `total * total` is equivalent to `total ** 2`; this is easier to use for things like

```
def square_of_sum():
    total = 0
    for x in xrange(11):
        if x <= 10:
            total += x
            x += 1
    print total ** 2
```

But, if I were you, I'd just use

```
sum(range(11))**2
```